# How to store dates with different levels of precision in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, date

I am storing data on journal papers from PubMed in Postgres, and I want to store the publication date of the paper. However, sometimes the date is [just a year](http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&rettype=abstract&id=27433467) (see the `PubDate` field), sometimes it is a month and a year, and sometimes it is a day, month and year.

What's a sensible way to store this data in my database?

If I use a Postgres date field, I obviously need to specify day and month as well, but I'll need to invent them in some cases, and I don't like the idea of losing the information about the date's precision.

For my purposes I *think* I will only need the year, but I don't know that to be true for all possible future purposes.

Perhaps I should just have text fields for `day`, `month` and `year`, and then I can always convert them to a date field in the future if I need them?

Comment: Yes, your suggestion at the end seems very reasonable to me. You could also add a `CHECK` constraint to check that if `day` is not null, then `month` is not null too. An alternative would be to create a date column and a second column to indicate the accuracy of the date column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ISO-8601 in Postgres: How to insert only year in type date? (incomplete date-time values)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599997/iso-8601-in-postgres-how-to-insert-only-year-in-type-date-incomplete-date-tim)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would store it as `date` and store the precision as well.

For example:

```
CREATE TYPE date_prec AS ENUM ('day', 'month', 'year');

CREATE TABLE pub (
   pub_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   pub_date date NOT NULL,
   pub_date_prec date_prec NOT NULL
);
```

Then you can query the table like this:

```
SELECT pub_id, date_trunc(pub_date_prec::text, pub_date)::date FROM pub;
```

to ignore any “random” day and month values in `pub_date`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Date field and have another field - lets say 'dateflag' of type integer. You have have values such as 1 for use full date, 2 for use date and month, 3 for use year only. This way while retrieving the data you would know what to do. Of course for opt 2 and 3 you will need to put in a dummy date/month besides the year while doing the insert.

Your idea of 3 fields is perfectly valid too - but it will require lots of checking to be sure you maintain the sanctity of the date (Like if day is there - then month has to be there, rules for value of days and months etc).